# Only 'Test Memory' is clickable in 22.04 desktop bootable usb disk

Tags: 22.04, live-usb, memory-test

[screenshot of GRUB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq7PB.jpg) It is NOT working on the one system I wanted it to run. (Working on other 2 systems). Please refer attached, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a keyboard? Can you navigate in the grub menu with the arrow keys (up-arrow and/or down arrow and then activate with the enter key?